# Crontab command not outputting any log

Tags: command-line, cron

I've been reading this great post:

https://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

And I decided to modify a line of my cron task to output my echos and any problems it might encouter. My cron tab line looks like this:

```
30 08 * * * /root/scripts_server/backup_daily.sh &>/var/log/bkp_daily.log
```

The script runs correctly (I can confirm that the backups were made and transfered) and the output file is created (bkp_daily.log), but it is empty.

Can any one point out a problem?

EDIT:

This is an example of a line in the script:

```
echo "--------------Sincronización de git remotos a locales-----------------------"
```

Comment: Are you sure the script prints output?

Comment: There are serveral echos in the script. Shouldn't that be printed? When I executed the script I got a ton of output (mainly because it tells me all the file it compresseses besides my own echos)

Comment: I copied and pasted a line of the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `&>` is a `bash` extension, try using the standard shell syntax:

```
30 08 * * * /root/scripts_server/backup_daily.sh >/var/log/bkp_daily.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Yes! I've tried it with a simple ls and it worked. I suppose it will work for my other scripts. Thank you!